Angular 15: The FormGroup value property doesn't return nested FormGroups
I have the following FormGroup definitions:
readonly firstGroup = new FormGroup({
  account: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
  password: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true })
});

readonly secondGroup = new FormGroup({
  account: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
  password: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true })
});

readonly control = new FormControl<boolean>(false);

readonly group = new FormGroup({
  control: this.control,
  first: this.firstGroup
  second: this.secondGroup
});


I've defined the FormGroups separately to make them easier to manipulate within the component.
Within the component I use the value property of the FormGroup (AbstractControl actually) to get all of the FormGroups values (those that aren't disabled of course) but when using said property all I get back is the value for the single control FormControl value.
const values = this.group.value;
console.log(values); // Prints { control: false }

This is unexpected, I thought I would receive the following object:
{
  control: false,
  first: {
     username: '',
     password: '',
  },
  second: {
     username: '',
     password: '',
  }
}

Note that none of the controls are disabled!
Now, if I instead define my FormGroup in the following way:
readonly control = new FormControl<boolean>(false);

readonly group = new FormGroup({
  control: this.control,
  first: new FormGroup({
    account: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
    password: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true })
  })
  second: new FormGroup({
    account: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
    password: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true })
  })
});


Then I receive the object I was expecting when calling the value property.
{
  control: false,
  first: {
     username: '',
     password: '',
  },
  second: {
     username: '',
     password: '',
  }
}

I'm confused as to why this is happening.
I'm intentionally using the value getter so that disabled controls are not included in the result.
Is anyone able to shed some light on what's going on?
Why does the value property return two different objects based on how I've defined the form?

issue not reproducible stackblitz please reproduce and update on the question

@NarenMurali I already tried to repro with stackblitz and wasn't able to... I'm unsure if it's because stackblitz is using a newer Angular version.. Or maybe My compiler settings?

try syncing up the angular version in package.json and try to replicate it

a type error? you forget the comma when define the formGroup: new FormGroup({control: this.control, first: this.firstGroup , second: this.secondGroup}); have you another variable (or template variable) you called also "group"? have you use equal to compare instead of two equals? I'm pretty sure that it's not a problem with the versions
